# Any better (shorter) way to generate random strings?

Tags: php

Any random number between `0` to `100` can be generated like this:

```
<?php
    $min = 0;
    $max = 100;
    $random =  rand($min,$max);
?>
```

Now I can place this `$random` anywhere in my file to generate a random number. But the problem is when I place this on more than one place all those places have same value *(if one random number is `17` all will be `17`)*.

I am doing something like this to do that in more than one place:

```
    $random2 =  rand($min,$max);
    $random3 =  rand($min,$max);
    $random4 =  rand($min,$max);
    $random5 =  rand($min,$max);
```

And placing those in all locations.

Doing so takes more of my space in my script. Is there any better way to do what I want?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this random numbers?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari This is just an example. `$random` can be any value to CSS property.

Comment: You can put some random numbers in array with a `for` loop; or leave it without defining variables, for example, `$out = "Hello ".rand($min,$max)." world ".rand($min,$max)." lorem ".rand($min,$max)." ipsum"`

Comment: Why not working? Probably you do something wrong http://codepad.org/m4RXy8C9

Comment: @IOXenus What? C compiler, Codepad can handle a lot languages. Try again....

Comment: @OP also notice that this PHP `rand()` isn't "random". More info @ http://www.random.org/

Comment: @Bondye I'm not saying that my script isn't working. I want a shorter way. I don't want to do `$random[n] = rand($min,$max);` each time.

Comment: If you want to generate more than one random number, you have to call the random number generator more than once. Yes. Not sure what other question you have.

Comment: If you get the content of this link http://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=100&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new you get realy random numbers for each request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not making a function?:

```
function myRand(){
    $min = 0;
    $max = 100;
    return mt_rand($min, $max);
}
echo myRand();
```

that way you have to call only the function.

Answer (score 0):

Founded this on stackoverflow long back

```
 function getRandom($lengthOfStringToGen)
 {
 $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$randString= '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $lengthOfStringToGen; $i++) {
    $randString.= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
}
return $randString;
}
```

Comment: Is it `$randtring` or `$randString`?

Comment: can be anything, its just a variable name

Comment: I think he asked because you initialized a string called $randtring, but then you assigned $randString. It might throw a notice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 function randd(){
 $min = 0;
$max = 100;
return $random =  rand($min,$max).'<br>';
}
echo $random = randd();
echo $random= randd();
echo $random= randd();
echo $random= randd();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/*
* str_shuffle to generate a random series of characters based on those provided, uniqid added, then shuffled again.
* substr will trim the output down to between 10 and 12 characters randomly.
*/

//Generate 10 Random Strings
$i = 1;
while($i <= 10){
echo substr(str_shuffle(uniqid(str_shuffle("abcdefghjkmnpqrstwxyzABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTWXYZ23456789"))), 0, rand(10,12))."<br/>";
$i++;
}

?>
```